# $_GET & "=" -- Syntax Error

Tags: php, get, include

For example link;

http://example.com/cast?Channel=STACKo

ChannelDatas.php;

```
 $STACKo_YAYIN = 'overflow';
```

Index.php;

```
  include '/***/Library/ChannelDatas.php';

  158 $_GET['Channel'] . '_YAYIN' = $insalik;
  159 $url = 'http://example.com/data/'.$insalik.'.info/weekly_'.$insalik.'.info_tvprofil.net.xml';
```

Target print:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/data/overflow.info/weekly_overflow.info_tvprofil.net.xml'
```

Error page:

```
 <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in <b>/***/v1/Index.php</b> on line <b>158</b><br />
```

What's wrong? Thank you!

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to do here...

Comment: You've a wrong assigning on line 158. It should be `$insalik = $_GET['Channel'] . '_YAYIN';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer to `$STACKo_YAYIN` in this way:

```
$STACKo_YAYIN = 'overflow';
$insalik = ${$_GET['Channel'] . '_YAYIN'};
$url = 'http://example.com/data/'.$insalik.'.info/weekly_'.$insalik.'.info_tvprofil.net.xml';
```

Comment: If you have a bunch of config values you want to address: Put them into an array! Don't create individual variables, because these can only be addressed with variable variables, and this actually is a security nightmare! You make available EVERY existing variable via a GET parameter (if it has the suffix "_YAYIN").

Comment: @Sven Totally, this kind of variable defining has security issues and that's another subject. But we just answered the OP needs.

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Don't recommend insecure practices! Others will read this and say "This is how it works, because it was written on Stackoverflow!" The least thing you should do is alert the OP that his intention is very dangerous! I did this by downvoting and commenting. And giving a better answer.

Comment: @Sven you can alert him by not commenting here but at his post.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need like this

```
$insalik = $_GET['Channel'] . '_YAYIN';
```

You are using `$insalik` for `$url`.So you need to assign that value to `$insalik`.You made it reverse.

Answer (score 0):

The bad things start here:

ChannelDatas.php;

```
$STACKo_YAYIN = 'overflow';
```

This should rather be:

```
$YAYIN = array(
    "STACKo" => 'overflow',
);
```

And then access is easy:

```
if (isset($YAYIN[$_GET['channel']]) {
    $url = 'http://example.com/data/'.$YAYIN[$_GET['channel']].'.info/weekly_'.$YAYIN[$_GET['channel']].'.info_tvprofil.net.xml';
} else {
    // what if there is no value for the channel?
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use following

```
$_GET['Channel'] = '_YAYIN'.$insalik;
```

Answer (score -1):

`$_GET['Channel'] . '_YAYIN'` is a string. You cannot assign (`=`) values to a string.
You need it the other way around (assign this string to a variable)

or maybe `${$_GET['Channel'] . '_YAYIN'} = $insalik`

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a variable variable:

```
$insalik = ${$_GET['Channel'].'_YAYIN'};
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score -1):

Try refrence variable

```
$temp = $_GET['Channel'] . '_YAYIN';
$insalik = $$temp;
```

Comment: Nobody really needs variable variables. Maintenance hell ensues.

Comment: @Sven he is trying to make a variable on run time so its good to use variable referencing to a varibel.